# h2o categorical_encoding understanding when to use and why

Tags: r, h2o

I'm trying to understand the pros/cons and when to use the various encoding options that are available to me in h2o with the parameter 'categorical_encoding'.

It would be helpful if people could point out general rules of thumb on how to use this.

Typically I use the 'Enum' value because I like how all categorical values are grouped together when looking at feature importance.  On the other hand, xgboost's default value is 'label-encoder' I believe, which breaks things up by categorical level/value.

Unfortunately, I don't really know where to begin or questions to ask around these other values available:

- one hot internal
- one hot explicit
- sort_by_response
- enum_limited
- enum
  -label-encoder

Again, I primarily stick with enum, sometimes label-encoder, but honestly I don't know practical implications of these various options.  Would love a generalized understanding of when one might be better than other from someone knowledgeable !

Comment: hi @runningbirds since this isn't a coding specific question, it would be great if you could post this to stackexchanges cross-validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h2o

Comment: thanks so much for posting this question to the correct location !

Answer (score 0):

As requested (thanks!) this question was reposted to cross-validated. So the answer on what the pros and cons are can be found at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376203/categorical-encoding-in-h2o-what-is-the-difference-between-the-options